# Drupal 8 performance regressions. Would it be a solution for high traffic online communities?

Tags: performance

There were some legitimate concerns about Drupal 8 potential performance regressions as a result of being built on top of Symfony2. Drupal 8 Beta-14 is the latest release; It seems that the Drupal 8 big release it comes apace. As per all the benchmarks I saw until I noticed that Drupal 8 is much slower than Drupal 7 especially for logged in users which is kind of a bummer.

Isn't Drupal supposed to be used for online communities where logged in users could interact? For displaying news and blogs there are already other software much convenient to use such as Wordpress. What kind of server would support such an expensive product? In this scenario, will be Drupal 8 a solution for high traffic online communities where logged-in users could post things and make comments and interact with each other?

Shouldn't this newer version of Drupal better than the old one? In terms of performance it doesn't seems so. This is why I'm thinking to find alternatives to Drupal for my potential clients. I'm not sure that financially speaking would worth to develop an online community website in Drupal and pay a lot for hosting and development.

Comment: In terms of performance it is perfectly usual that newer software requires better hardware. Drupal 7 was released 5 years ago. You wouldn't expect new games to work better than old ones on 5yo computer, right? You would expect them to look better, be more extensible and so on. Same with Adobe Photoshop, operating systems, office suites, and many others. Why would CMS be different?

Comment: The questions are sightly different, but the bulk of the information we could give you is in the duplicate. Whether or not it's suitable for high traffic online communities is not something that can be objectively answered unfortunately. It depends on too many factors (level of traffic, server hardware, balancing, etc). You need to benchmark under real-world conditions specific to your app to be sure of something like that

Comment: I had different expectations from Drupal8. **I read lots of articles on how Drupal8 would be faster and better than Drupal7.** bumkum! Well, right now all benchmarks are showing that is 2-3 times slower than Drupal 7 - Drupal 7 was not very speedy but was kind of good enough. This means that the hosting should be 2-3 times better. 2-3 times more money spent on hosting. On one hand using a open source cms would save you money, but on the other hand the hosting solution is more expensive.

Comment: It _can be_ much faster, when you have the caches primed and ready. That's the important bit. 'Better' can't really be objectively measured as it depends what you mean (as a programmer my primary concern is DX, which is a million times better in D8, for example). Other than the question that can't be answered (whether Drupal 8 will work for an unspecified app on unspecified hardware), is there anything else you need to know? I ask because this reads like you're venting frustration, rather than trying to solve a real-world problem

Comment: Not sure if cashing everything is the solution. Probably this is why it is so non-performing for logged in users. The end user does not give a damn on DX. They get frustrated when the page they're trying to access is not loading. I'm not trying to solve a real world problem. I'm trying to figure out if Drupal 8 is the way to go. And yes, I'm frustrated that it regressed in terms of performance.

Comment: I think Wim has been the goto person on the latest performance improvements (esp caching contexts) since Berdir answered back in March.  I'll see if I can get him to write an updated answer.

Comment: @rungurean It's the solution to the current problem, and that's all that can be said. Thankfully (for me), the developers didn't share your view that end users are more important than devs. That's a sure-fire way to alienate arguably the most important part of your open source community. I think you're forgetting about the size and scale of the Drupal project; it's not 5 devs sitting round a table, and it hasn't been written for you and your app. You've already made up your mind that it's too slow, so what's the problem? You don't have to use it, why are you so keen to carry on bashing it?

Comment: (not being combative, by the way, I just don't see the point of flogging a dead horse)

Comment: you're right :)

Comment: @Clive "Hope dies hard"

Comment: @ar7max right ...

Comment: @Clive - you marked this thread as a duplicate of another thread but I think  it is not the same thing. This thread is not public. Nobody can see what I asked.

Comment: Anyone can see it @rungurean, it would only be invisible to the general public if it was deleted. It's just not the right sort of question for Q+A I'm afraid, too many open-ended questions that could only reasonably be answered by the people who actually made the individual decisions, not the community at large. It would be an appropriate discussion for the core issue queue, just not Q+A I'm afraid

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for your help. I'll post my questions to the drupal forum.